# What it the intuition behind basis, filters as neighborhoods and neighborhoods?

Tags: general-topology, filters

I know every definition, but as hard as I think I can't get the intuition behind such objects.

For example, the definitions I am familiar with the most:

> Take $X$ a topological space with topology $\tau.$
>
> A base for such topology is a subset $\mathcal{B} \subset \tau,$ such every element $A \in \tau$ is written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}.$

Ok, but what it does mean in fact? How can I understand this?

For the second part, what is the precise intuition behind neighborhoods? In particular, there is a definition via filters:

> Take $X$ as a set with no topology a priori. Then we say that $\mathcal{F}$ is a filter on $X$ if:
>
> $\emptyset \in \mathcal{F};$
>
> $A,B\in\mathcal{F} \Rightarrow A\cap B \in \mathcal{F};$
>
> $A \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \forall B$ that contains $A$, $B\in \mathcal{F}.$

Ok, so we induce on $X$ a notion of proximity as follows:

> For each $x \in X$, $\mathcal{V}$ is a system of nerighborhoods for $x$ if $\mathcal{V}$ is a filter and for each $V \in \mathcal{V}$, $x\in V.$
> We call $V \in \mathcal{V}$ a neighborhood of $x$.

Then, why we are able to say that $y$ is closer of $x$ at the measure that $\{V \in \mathcal{V} : y \in V\}$?

> A set $A \subseteq X$ is open if $A$ is a neighborhood for every $x \in A.$
>
> Assuming now that we have a notion of topology, we call a neighborhood system of $x \in X$ a collection of sets $V$ such that there are $U$ open in $X$ with $x\in U \subset V$.

How can I connect these objects on the two definitions of topology?
Does the notion of proximity remain?

And at the end, what I find most difficult to interpret,

> A collection $\mathcal{V}'$ of subsets of a neighborhood system $\mathcal{V}$ at $x$ is a fundamental neighborhood system if for every open $A$ such $x \in A$, there is $V \in \mathcal{V}'$ such that $x \in V \subset A.$

How to interpret this? What is the difference of this for a neighborhood system?

Comment: Basis are like open balls in metric spaces.